# Landscape ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

When I change my orientationon landscape my photo will be only half ... I want when I change my orientation to be like on facebook , to show full picture .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another layout for horizontal layout. if you want your portrait view to be different from your landscape view. you must create another `XML` file for landscape. 
The two `XML` file will be handled by the same JAVA code. although you can programmatically listen to orientation change but would prefer the different layout for Different Orientation.

> create two types of layout directories to handle orientation . layout-land layout-port put the xml with the same name in both the directory.  example if you have main.xml file then add have to put it in both directory.

[Documentation on supporting multiple screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: but , how can I connect this new layout with landscape view ?

Comment: you don't need to connect it, once you create the layout, android will automatically detect which layout to use when in portrait or  landscape mode. when you `accelerometer` is horizontal it loads the `layout-land`

Comment: so you're saying , I will have to do the same layout with the same id's in a new folder called "layout-land" ?

Comment: its depends, normally that should be the case, but sometime, the two layout do not have the same widgets. landscape may have more widget than landscape, you may have to handle that programmatically. but if its the same number of layout. then you don't have to do anything just do the same layout with the same id widgets